# php mysqli fetch data and divide two variables toFixed(2) / two decimal places

Tags: php

I have been able to divide two variables from a mysqli query... How do i divide the number to two decimal places / toFIxed(2)

**php**

```
$Date = $_GET['date'];
    $Win = 'Win';

$testsql="
SELECT 
count(*) AS bet_count,
SUM(IF(result ='$Win', 1, 0)) AS win_count
FROM bets WHERE betDate = '$Date' GROUP BY betDate 
";

$testresult = mysqli_query($connection, $testsql);

while ($testrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($testresult))
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='text-center'>".($testrow['bet_count']/$testrow['win_count']). "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

So, the bet_count / win_count works as expected.....I just need the integer e.g. 2.371237234 to two decimal places 2.37

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try with [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

```
<?php
$Date = $_GET['date'];
$Win = 'Win';

$testsql = "
   SELECT 
      count(*) AS bet_count,
      SUM(IF(result ='$Win', 1, 0)) AS win_count
   FROM bets WHERE betDate = '$Date' GROUP BY betDate 
";

$testresult = mysqli_query($connection, $testsql);

while ($testrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($testresult)) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    $value = number_format($testrow['bet_count']/$testrow['win_count'], 2, '.', '');
    echo "<td class='text-center'>".$value."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: wow...that was simple, thanks, when able to, I will mark a answer, :)

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson: dont forgot to accept correct answe, this will help to future visitor.